# UserService.SavedUserGroup Not Saving data on 1st time (Umbraco 7.8.1)

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am facing issues while saving UserService.SavedUserGroup delegate (event), when i fired save event in Users Group and change its permissions,it's not reflecting changes on 1st time and its save the changes on 2 time.

Thank you.
This is code sample i implemented. When i hit Save its come on this event and execute every single line but not save changes. 2nd time its working as accepted.  `

```
UserService.SavedUserGroup += GroupServiceSaved;

public void GroupServiceSaved(IUserService sender,Umbraco.Core.Events.SaveEventArgs<IUserGroup> args)
         {
            IEnumerable<IContent> contents;
            contents = objCommonRepository.GetContentType("home");
}
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code :)

Comment: hello @Mikkel  i edited my post and some sample code.